Wallet and network selection for bitcoin URI BIP21 payment invoked through QR Code
I'm building an application to generate a payment link to be provided as a QR code.
The encoded string is a Bitcoin URI scheme as defined in BIP21.
bitcoin:?amount=1
For me, this opens a default wallet to populate the transaction. I do not know how this default it calculated.
I'd like to give a user options. Maybe they have multiple wallets, maybe they want to use a testnet.
I can't find any documentation on how to allow for these things.
Are they possible?
